# Selenium Handle Stale Element in a for loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I have an UI like this:

[image]

I have to choose each attachment and click to download or delete.

To download:

```
// get the list of radio buttons
List<WebElement> attachments = driver().findElements(By.className("select-attachment"));
for (WebElement attachment : attachments) {
    attachment.click();
    driver().findElement(By.className("download-attachment")).click();   
}
```

This works fine, the attachments will be clicked and downloaded.

But I am facing a problem with detele test case. Because when I click Delete button, there will be an `Alert` dialog to ask "Are you sure blah", after I accept the dialog, I get the `StaleElementReferenceException`

To delete:

```
// get the list of radio buttons
List<WebElement> attachments = driver().findElements(By.className("select-attachment"));
for (WebElement attachment : attachments) {
    attachment.click();
    driver().findElement(By.className("delete-attachment")).click();
    Alert alert = alert().get();        
    alert.accept();
}
```

This works fine for the first attachment, but after I accept the `Alert`, the element `attachement` is no longer attached to the DOM, so when it loops to the second radio button, I get the `StaleElementReferenceException`.

I know with Stale element we have to `findElement` again. But since I have a list in `for` loop, I don't know how to handle it.

How can I still use `for` loop and be able to handle Stale element?

Comment: what screen do you see after accepting the alert?

Comment: @AdrianJimenez: The Alert is just overlayed on top of the attachments page. So after the alert, the focus is back to attachments page, but the element is no longer attachment to the DOM

Comment: after alert.accept, past this line List<WebElement> attachments = driver().findElements(By.className("select-attachment"));
if element does not exisit, then you need to execute steps to make attachments visible again